# Comparing date value with YEAR in Tableau

Tags: date, datetime, comparison, tableau-api, calculated-field

I've a calculated field in Tableau which has the Years (Date Value) from a date field. When I compare this calculated field with year of another field, I get error.

```
IF calculated_Field = YEAR(order_date)
...
```

1) calculated_Field is the one created using Date value of another field.

2) Order_date is a datetime field.

Error I see in the above IF statement says "Cant compare YEAR and INT values". 
When I solved that using below statement, it does not work as expected as IF returns FALSE.

```
IF INT(calculated_Field) = YEAR(order_date)
```

Comment: What is your calculated field defined as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the comparisons are both from YEAR()

```
IF YEAR(another_field) = YEAR(order_date)
```

1. `calculated_Field` is created using Date value of `another_field`.
2. `Order_date` is a datetime field.